# Using Week of the Year to Get Month via Lubridate in R

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I want to get the name of the month from the week number from the following data.

```
    cov$year_week <- c("2020-01", "2020-02", "2020-03", "2020-04", "2020-05", "2020-06", 
"2020-07", "2020-08", "2020-09", "2020-10")
```

I need to convert it as `2020-Jan, 2020-Jan, 2020-Jan....2020-Feb` as a column in dataframe. I am using `lubridate` as a choice.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

dummy <- data.frame(dumcol =seq.Date(as.Date('2020-01-01'),as.Date('2020-12-31'),by='week'))

dummy %>%
mutate(week=week(dumcol),months=month(dumcol,label=T)) %>% 
select(week,months)-> dummy

cov %>%
select(year_week) %>%
separate(year_week,c('year','week')) %>% 
mutate(week=as.numeric(week)) %>% 
left_join(dummy,by='week') %>% 
mutate(new_col=paste0(year,'-',months))
```

[image]

**note : months are in my native language.**

Comment: sorry dear friend my week are from 0-53 for the full year. So, I need to get `December` for week number `53`. Your code will work when I have months and not weeks as the number.

Comment: oh sorry, let me fix

Comment: @ambrishdhaka how about now, can you check it out again ?

Comment: thanks I guess the week number is fixed for each month irrespective of the year.

Comment: yes lubridate gets it through, you can approve my answer if your problem is fixed

Answer (score 1):

Converting to datetime

```
cov <- c("2020-01", "2020-02", "2020-03", "2020-04", "2020-05", "2020-06", 
                   "2020-07", "2020-08", "2020-09", "2020-10")

strptime(paste0(cov,"-1"),"%Y-%W-%w")
 [1] "2020-01-06 CET" "2020-01-13 CET" "2020-01-20 CET" "2020-01-27 CET" "2020-02-03 CET"
 [6] "2020-02-10 CET" "2020-02-17 CET" "2020-02-24 CET" "2020-03-02 CET" "2020-03-09 CET"
```

To get your desired result you just need another call to format

```
format(strptime(paste0(cov,"-1"),"%Y-%W-%w"),"%Y-%b")
 [1] "2020-jan." "2020-jan." "2020-jan." "2020-jan." "2020-feb." "2020-feb." "2020-feb."
 [8] "2020-feb." "2020-mar." "2020-mar."
```

Note: I used %W and %w

```
%w
Weekday as decimal number (0–6, Sunday is 0).

%W
Week of the year as decimal number (00–53) using Monday as the first day of week (and typically with the first Monday of the year as day 1 of week 1). The UK convention.
```

Comment: @ambrishdhaka You may be interested in `%V ... Week of the year as decimal number (01–53) as defined in ISO 8601`.